# draft js bullet point from word doc

Tags: reactjs, ms-word, draftjs

For my use case copy and paste from Microsoft Word ist a common task. 
Draft.js does not handle this very well right now,Is there any plugins or anything available to provide this functionality?

Not the whole .docx standard but Bullet point lists and base formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this fork of draft-js](https://github.com/neuron-digital/draft-js)
OR
fork [draft-js](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js) and merge [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/pull/1068)

Then use this code

```
  <Editor
    editorState={this.state.editorState}
    handlePastedText={handlePastedText}
  >

  handlePastedText = (text, html, callback) => {
    // handle MS Word unordered list
    const modifiedHtml = html.replace(/<p class=MsoListParagraph[\s\S]*?>·([\s\S]*?)<\/p>/g, '<li>$1</li>');

    callback(text, modifiedHtml);
  }
```

to handle unordered lists.

To handle other formatting you can write your own regex.